# My Android hybrid application is crashing in API19 4.4.4 getting a libc error

Tags: javascript, android, hybrid-mobile-app

My Android hybrid application is crashing in API19 4.4.4 getting a libc error

```
viewAction.getButton().addEventListener(eversify.ButtonController.TAP, function () {
    function openEdition () {
        var viewEditionEvent = _this.createEvent(EventTypes.VIEW_EDITION_EVENT);
                            viewEditionEvent.editionModel = _editionModel;
                            _this.dispatchEvent(viewEditionEvent);
     }
```

Comment: A/libc(1491): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=128), thread 1572 (Thread-113)